# How to get most related question by keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to find an answer by reviewing the user input and check what answer does have the most matching keywords.
I have an object array. When a user submits the form, I want to look into the user input and check what answer has the most tags that are inside the user input.

I don't know how to start.
Does anyone know how I'm able to do this in `JS` or `jQuery`?
I need to find the answer where the most keywords (tags) are in the user input.

This is the code I have now:

```js
var objectArr = [{
    "tags": ["windows", "3cx", "webclient", "hoe", "venster", "windows-venster"],
    "answer": "Maak op je bureaublad een sneltoets aan en kies als doel:<br/>“C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” –app=https://pbx000000.fluxcloud.eu:5001/webclient <br/>Hier verander je de 000000 in de link naar het juiste PBX-nummer wat er hoort."
  },
  {
    "tags": ["swyx", "toestel", "opstarten", "blijft", "opnieuw", "mijn", "werkt niet"],
    "answer": "Tijdens een software-update is de stroom mogelijk van het toestel af geweest. <br/> Je kan het toestel opsturen naar ons om de software te herstellen.<br/> De kosten van het herstellen van het toestel bedraagt €25,-"
  },
  {
    "tags": ["toestel", "vast", "bellen", "kan niet", "werkt niet"],
    "answer": "Zorg ervoor dat de telefonie-applicatie (SwyxIt!) is opgestart en dat jouw toestel is ingelogd op je eigen naam.<br/> Als dat het geval is, ga dan in SwyxIt! naar: Instellingen – CTI – CTI gebruiken – start koppelen."
  },
  {
    "tags": ["client", "swyx", "inloggen", "kan niet", "werkt niet"],
    "answer": "Controleer de tijd op de pc, deze mag niet meer dan 3 minuten afwijken van de tijd op de Swyxserver.<br/> Klopt de tijd op je pc, maar kun je nog steeds niet inloggen?<br/> Controleer dan je SwyxIt!-versie. Deze mag niet nieuwer zijn dan de OZMO cloud-omgeving."
  },
  {
    "tags": ["beltoon", "geen", "swyx", "swyxphone", "mijn"],
    "answer": "SwyxPhone L640 laat in het display een belsymbool zien waar een streep doorheen staat.<br/> De beltonen van het toestel zijn op dat moment uitgeschakeld.<br/> Door de <b>“*”</b> toets voor langere tijd in te drukken, kun je de beltonen weer activeren."
  }
];

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  var input = $("#user_input").val();
  // the part that searches in the object array for an answer by tags that are inside user input
  var answer = "find in object";

  /////////
  $("#answer").html(answer);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="user_input">
<button id="submit">Send</button>
<div id="answer">

</div>
```

I tried this:

```
 var answer = "";
 for(var i=0;i<objectArr.length;i++){
    for(var o=0;o<objectArr[i].tags.length;o+++){
       if($("#user_input").val().includes(objectArr[i].tags[o])){
         answer = objectArr[i]['answer'];
       }
     }
  }
  $("#answer").html(answer);
```

But In this way it just looks up one keyword.
I want to find the one with the most keywords matching.

Comment: let's start by knowing that your variable `json` (that @mplungjan changed to `objectArr`) is not holding a real JSON, ok? but, a tip is, loop the array called `json`, for each index, get the `json[i].tags` then you can use the `.includes(input)` to check if it have the typed value

Comment: yeah sorry, I was too busy with json when I made this object, I miss 
interpretated it, Its should be a object array

Comment: What have you tried till now (lijkt me meer een opgave voor ons dan een vraag). This looks like an assignment, not a question. What is the expected input that you would get from a user? What kind of search options would you like to include?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I need to loop the tags array in search for matching keywords

Comment: yes, I know, my tip above is telling you one of many methods you can use to achieve that

Comment: @Jbadminton how about using regex. You can create a regex of containing the list of the words you want to search. Then just compile the different objects to match them to given regex. Regex would be fast and handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this

You can count the results to narrow them

```js
var objectArr = [{ "tags": ["windows", "3cx", "webclient", "hoe", "venster", "windows-venster"], "answer": "Maak op je bureaublad een sneltoets aan en kies als doel:<br/>“C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” –app=https://pbx000000.fluxcloud.eu:5001/webclient <br/>Hier verander je de 000000 in de link naar het juiste PBX-nummer wat er hoort." }, { "tags": ["swyx", "toestel", "opstarten", "blijft", "opnieuw", "mijn", "werkt niet"], "answer": "Tijdens een software-update is de stroom mogelijk van het toestel af geweest. <br/> Je kan het toestel opsturen naar ons om de software te herstellen.<br/> De kosten van het herstellen van het toestel bedraagt €25,-" }, { "tags": ["toestel", "vast", "bellen", "kan niet", "werkt niet"], "answer": "Zorg ervoor dat de telefonie-applicatie (SwyxIt!) is opgestart en dat jouw toestel is ingelogd op je eigen naam.<br/> Als dat het geval is, ga dan in SwyxIt! naar: Instellingen – CTI – CTI gebruiken – start koppelen." }, { "tags": ["client", "swyx", "inloggen", "kan niet", "werkt niet"], "answer": "Controleer de tijd op de pc, deze mag niet meer dan 3 minuten afwijken van de tijd op de Swyxserver.<br/> Klopt de tijd op je pc, maar kun je nog steeds niet inloggen?<br/> Controleer dan je SwyxIt!-versie. Deze mag niet nieuwer zijn dan de OZMO cloud-omgeving." }, { "tags": ["beltoon", "geen", "swyx", "swyxphone", "mijn"], "answer": "SwyxPhone L640 laat in het display een belsymbool zien waar een streep doorheen staat.<br/> De beltonen van het toestel zijn op dat moment uitgeschakeld.<br/> Door de <b>“*”</b> toets voor langere tijd in te drukken, kun je de beltonen weer activeren." } ]; 

const finder = function(search, target) { return search.map(function (val) { return target.filter(function (e) {return val === e;}).length;});}


$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#answer").empty();
  const input = $("#user_input").val().toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let answer = "Nothing found";
  let most = 0;
  objectArr.forEach(item => {
    const count = finder(input,item.tags).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    if (count > most) {
      answer = item.answer
    }  
  })
  $("#answer").html(answer);
});


/* Just find any
  var answers = objectArr.filter(item => {
    return input.some(r => item.tags.includes(r))
  })
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user_input" value="swyx toestel opstarten" />
  <button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
<div id="answer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to find 1 answer that has the most matching tags, not it just finds all answers where one keyword is found

Comment: I have updated to show the count. You will have to do the handling of `"werkt niet"` as one tag yourself